# How to speed up Dynamic Select in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I was able to create a dynamic dropdown list for Province and City by using an Adjacent list model that references to itself and jquery but it takes forever to load.

It works how I wanted it to work however; this process takes 7473.4ms to load every time it renders the form since I have 1718 rows in my locations table and it tries to load all 1718 of them one at a time.

I found out that what's making it load longer is the grouped_collection_select but I can't think of a faster alternative for this. Is there a query tweak you can advise me to make this form load faster?

The model looks like this:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  belongs_to :parent_location, class_name: Location
  has_many :child_locations, class_name: Location, foreign_key: "parent_id"
end
```

and the db (locations table) looks something like this but it has 1718 rows:

```
id  location         parent_id
1   Philippines 
2   Metro Manila        1
3   Abra                1
4   Caloocan City       2
5   City of Las Pinas   2
6   Pilar               3
7   Sallapadan          3
```

I was able to make the dynamic dropdown by using a "collection_select" for the provinces dropdown and a "grouped_collection_select" for the cities in my _form.html.haml:

```
= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.where(parent_id: "1"), :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a Province"}, id: "province"
= f.grouped_collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :child_locations, :name, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a City/Municipality"}, id: "city"
```

then I used jQuery to show only the cities under the selected province in my js.cofee file:

```
jQuery ->
    city = $('#city').html()
    $('#province').change->
        province = $('#province :selected').text()
        options = $(city).filter("optgroup[label='#{province}']").html()
        if options
            $('#city').html(options)
        else
            $('#city').empty()
```

Comment: A common solution is to use something like Select2, and get the content on-demand with AJAX after the user types a few characters (eg. `Bos` would complete to `Boston`, and some other cities starting with `Bos`). This way you don't have to render a view with 1,718 `<option>` tags, and get only the few you want... A second way is to cache the result of the `grouped_collection` function in something like redis or memcached.

Comment: I'm looking into both options now thanks! I have another question though, is there a way to not load the contents of `grouped_collection` when nothing is selected in `collection_select`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to lower down the speed by using preload in `grouped_collection`:

it preloads all child_locations which made the loading time faster

```
 = f.grouped_collection_select :location_id, Location.preload(:child_locations), :child_locations, :name, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a City/Municipality"}, id: "city"
```